# How to solve Line height issue with custom font in HTML?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have an issue while using custom font(poppins-regular.ttf). The issue is when I set background-color for span tag which is wrapper of text.

The words like g,y,.. etc got cut at the bottom. But, If I change the font-family from poppinsRegular to tahoma it looks good.

**But the real issue here is i need to maintain same line-height**

```css
.passageBody, .passageBody2 {
  width: 414px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.passageBody2 {
  font-family: tahoma;
}
.highlightPhrase {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="passageBody">
  <span>“Good-bye to you and your funny feet.</span>
  <span class="highlightPhrase">Thanks for all the eggs to eat!” I was speaking to Bess, our chicken, and Mother laughed.</span>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="passageBody2">
  <span>“Good-bye to you and your funny feet.</span>
  <span class="highlightPhrase">Thanks for all the eggs to eat!” I was speaking to Bess, our chicken, and Mother laughed.</span>
</div>
```

[Example jsFiddle link here...](https://jsfiddle.net/VEERASUTHAN/bk1cag2m/)

Comment: as i remember, line height doesn't need a unit like px. just put 1.2 1.5 or else

Comment: Thanks @obink, I gave line height 1.3 and it still shows the same issue

Comment: I think Poppins font have problem with design line-height. I am using this font for our website and it don't display exactly authough I am changing line-height.

Answer (score 2):

You can either remove the line-height property or [try to set](https://jsfiddle.net/bk1cag2m/5/) it in *em* units.

```
line-height: 1.5em;
```

**Edit 1**

If you don't want to change line-height, use vertical align with inline display

```
.highlightPhrase {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

**Edit 2**
The above code might have visually changed the line height. So [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/bk1cag2m/6/) might be an elegant solution to your problem. Just wrap the content in another element and set the position to relative, so that background of each line will not hide the above line.

```
 .highlightPhrase span {
   position:relative;
 }
```

or you can use some small image as background and repeat it to highlight entire text.

Comment: yeah, changing/increasing line height solves the problem but i am in need to maintain the same line height and to solve the issue. Is there a way to edit fonts? because, it seems font contains some extra space on top and bottom

Comment: I've updated the answer without changing `line-height`

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is the vertical placement of the glyphs.
Designer decided to set the font glyphs like that.

So, basically designer decided how much space there is below the baseline, and how much space is above the height of uppercase letters. Typically these spaces are equal, but they don't need to be.

I think that only solution for you is to put bigger `line-height` on the paragraph that is using that font or just choose a different font.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment.. Is there any way to edit custom font and how to remove the extra space.? because, I am in a situation that can't the line-height or font. but, however i need to solve this i don't know how.

Comment: I never did this, but there are font editors where you can manipulate fonts.
This one is free: https://fontforge.github.io/ . Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change:
`line-height: 32px;` to `line-height: auto;`

Comment: Is there any way to solve this issue without changing line-height..?

Comment: You will probably have to manually edit the font; custom fonts can be buggy.  Setting the line height to auto is your best bet and it is only one extra line of code, so I don't see an issue with using the line-height property.

Comment: `auto` is an invalid value of the [`line-height` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) (MDN). Tested both in Fx and Chr DevTools. Also about the font: it's probably _not a bug but a feature©_ : that's a designer's choice (which is annoying in CSS, granted, because we've to accomodate on a per-font basis without so much tools at our disposal...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.highlightPhrase {
    padding:5px;
}
```